# Azure Data Factory Pipepline with Multiple Downstream Activity Slow in Downstream Scheduler Starting

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created an ADF pipeline with two linked activities, the first one to run a stored procedure and the 2nd activity (Copy Data) to copy data from a Azure DW to Azure SQL DB table. To link these two I have put the output dataset of the stored procedure as an input of the Copy Data activity even though that dataset is not used (there's a separate dataset for that).

Now the issue is when I get into "Monitor and Manage" and run the 2nd activity with "Rerun with upstream in Pipeline" the 1st stored procedure activity runs quickly and then the 2nd activity waits for about 5 mins before changing to In Progress. Why is this happening? Is it due to some time slicing issue? The Pipeline code is as below:

```
{
"name": "RunADLAProc",
"properties": {
    "description": "This will run the procedure for ADLA",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
            "typeProperties": {
                "storedProcedureName": "dbo.BackUpDatabaseLog",
                "storedProcedureParameters": {}
            },
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureSQLDatasetOutputforProc"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "retry": 3
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "StoredProcedureActivityTemplate"
        },
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from dbo.DatabaseLog"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureSqlDWInput"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AzureSQLDatasetOutputforProc"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureSQLDatasetOutput"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "CopyActivityTemplate"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2018-05-09T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2018-05-12T00:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "testdatafactory-v1_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ADFv2, it is more easily for debugging, and has a GUI authoring tool.
the UI tool is https://adf.azure.com

Comment: Thanks @Atvoid. I know V2 would really help, but unfortunately for this I am constrained to V1.